# How to fix 'NotADirectoryError' in Python on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I'm trying to walk through all the files on my computer and create a list of files larger than 100MB.  However, when walking through the files, I keep getting a 'NotADirectoryError.'  The way I understand my code, it should be looking base files in the second for loop, so I don't know why the 'NotADirectory' Error keeps getting raised.

I'm on a Mac using Python3.7.4.  I've tried adding an exception for 'NotADirectoryError', but it just gave me a 'FileNotFound Error,' so I figured adding exception upon exception wasn't the best way to solve this.

I think I'm misunderstanding how either os.walk or  os.path.getsize work, but after reviewing the documentation for both I'm still confused about what I'm doing wrong.

```
big_dict= {}

folder = os.path.abspath('/Users/')

#walking thru all the folders on my computer
for folders, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    #for each file that's bigger than 100 MB, add it to the 'big_dict'
    for filename in filenames:
        filename = os.path.join(folder, filename) +'/'
        file_size = os.path.getsize(filename) -- this line always gives the error
    #convert size to MB, add to big_dict as value with filename key
        if file_size > 1000000:
            big_dict[filename] = str(file_size/10000) + ' MB'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonbauer/size_check.py", line 17, in <module>
    file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
  File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../../../../Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/.localized/'
```

This is the error message I get when running the code.  As I said before, I'm trying to walk through all my files and add larger files to a list, but I keep encountering this error.

Comment: gotta `os.path.join(folders, filename)`

Comment: Why are you putting a slash on the end of a *file* name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
big_dict= {}

folder = os.path.abspath('/Users')

for root, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
  for filename in filenames:
    path = os.path.join(root, filename)
    if os.path.islink(path):
      continue
    file_size_mb = os.path.getsize(path) >> 20
    if file_size_mb > 100:
      file_size_mb_str = '{} MB'.format(file_size_mb)
      print(path, file_size_mb_str)
      big_dict[path] = file_size_mb_str
```

There are several problems in your code:

- `filename = os.path.join(folder, filename) +'/'` is incorrect, because `folder` is the base folder ('/Users/' in your case), not the actual folder you're walking.
- You need to skip links, because `getsize()` won't work on them
- `file_size > 1000000`: [os.path.getsize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) returns bytes